# Getting a 403 forbidden error on accessing AWS through ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

have been given access key and secret key through IAM. But restricted to open IAM through my AWS console.

After setting the environment variables for access key and secret key, region.

executed ./ec2.py --list which gives 403 forbidden error. What will be the problem?

And i have seen my policy.  the policy structure of my IAM is

```
Statements :
    Effect:allow
    Resource:ec2:*
```

Sorry I cannot copy my policy structure.  And i run behind a proxy. I don't think so proxy may be a drawback because am getting response.

The AWS console can be connected only by having a remote desktop gateway and a server. Will this may be a problem. But I have my access id  and secret id.

Comment: are you sure that all of the packages are updated?

Comment: ./ec2.py --list returning an error is not ansible, it's actually just using boto. check if you've configured it correctly in ~/.aws/credentials

Comment: Ya all the environment variables are set. And i have checked the policy of IAM and I have been given access to EC2, s3 and the "effect is allow". So I am wondering  what may be the problem. But still i get the 403 forbidden error

Comment: Please edit your question to include how you are running ./ec2.py and the full error it returns.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the mistake was the role assigning and corporate proxy.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you either do not have your environment set up correctly, or have the incorrect permissions to list metadata about your EC2 instances. If it's the former, you need to export your AWS_ACCESS and AWS_SECRET, e.g:

```
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your-aws-secret-key
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your-aws-access-key
```

If you are referring to permissions on the remote host for making calls to EC2 then you can do this by creating IAM **roles** which delegate various rights to instances that belong to the role.

Comment: Ya all the environment variables are set. And i have checked the policy of IAM and I have been given access to EC2, s3 and the "effect is allow". So I am wondering  what may be the problem. But still i get the 403 forbidden error